# Monitoring Azure Basic Internal Load Balancer

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer, internal-load-balancer

We are using basic internal load balancer for our clustered Azure Linux VMs. In production we would need monitoring in place to ascertain any issues in load balancing specifically if health probes are working or if backend VMs are responding. I am aware MS have come up with Standard Load Balancer for better monitoring. However that has a huge cost implication. I have also checked we get some monitoring capability if we use public basic load balancers however that is not our use case. For basic internal load balancer it seems we have to rely on crude ping tests and tcpdump utilities. I would like to know if anyone has experience in setting up some monitoring pattern with basic internal load balancers?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Azure Monitor logs are not available for internal Basic Load Balancers. You may vote [this user's voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/18753517-azure-internal-load-balancer) for improving this feature in the future.

As you know, you may deploy an additional small size VM as a jump server in the same VNet as the internal load balancer. Then use some utility like the PING test. Since the internal LB and its backends are always deployed in a VNet. It seems that you do not need to worry more about the networking connectivity from LB frontend to backends.